# How to check two condition with aspx inline code

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, webforms, inline-code

I am getting a value from database with using `Eval("price")`, i am checking if price is empty or null but i would like to check if price is equal to the zero or bigger than zero condition at the same time.

I am checking **IsNullOrEmpty** with this code:

```
<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("price").ToString()) ? "Not Available" : Eval("price").ToString() %>
```

I would like to check `if(price = 0)` say free or `else if(price > 0)` than show price condition at the same time and show message.

`<%# Eval("price").ToString() == "0" ? "FREE" : Eval("price").ToString() %>`  // Not working

Is it possible to check isnullorempty and price in same inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking is null or empty, it doesn't check if price is 0. Try something like

```
<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("price").ToString()) ? "Not Available" : Eval("price").ToString() == "0" ? "FREE" : Eval("price").ToString() %>
```